# ¿Cuál es la forma correcta de definir un array de anotaciones en kotlin o java?

Tags: java, kotlin, android-layout, layout, id

lo que he tratado es de esta forma:

```
val arrlay: Array<@LayoutRes Int> =[R.layout.tab_basales,R.layout.tab_pcs,R.layout.tab_portadores]
```

pero me genera el siguiente error

```
Unsupported [Collection literals outside of annotations]
This annotation is not applicable to target 'type usage'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu sintaxis es correcta pero simplemente `@LayoutRes` no soporta ese target.

En Java seria así:

```
int @LayoutRes [] arrlay = {R.layout.tab_basales,R.layout.tab_pcs, R.layout.tab_portadores};
```

Pero ten en cuenta que la gran mayoría de la anotaciones no soportan este uso.

`@LayoutRes` se usa en parámetros de una función para indicar que el valor que recibe deber ser el id de un layout y solamente sirve para mostrar una advertencia si esto no se cumple. En una propiedad no tiene mucho sentido porque ya sabes cual va a ser su valor y de todos modos el linter no funciona si el valor sale de una variable. Puedes eliminarla con seguridad y también recuerda que debes usar los arrays primitivos siempre que sea posible.

```
val arrlay = intArrayOf(R.layout.tab_basales, R.layout.tab_pcs, R.layout.tab_portadores)
```

`IntArray` es el equivalente a `int[]` (primitivo) en Java, mientras que `Array<Int>` es el equivalente a `Integer[]` (boxed)